# How to add custom triggers on lightgallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
`https://codepen.io/sumankarki/pen/LYVxMyR`
```

Here is the codepen link to a basic lightgallery page. Please, open the link and cross check with the question.

As seen on the codepen, we can trigger the popup when we click on image directly. I have created two buttons named as "Autoplay" & "Fullscreen" below gallery.

The question here is, how can we target only specific tasks through button?. For example, If we click on "Autoplay" button then the gallery should autoplay with popup and same goes for "Fullscreen" for fullscreen task. Can we achieve this through custom buttons that I made?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can do that. You just need to check the `lightgallery` plugin documentation found [here](https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/docs/api.html) and then connect your buttons with the proper `lightgallery` command via a jQuery selector and event handler.

For example, for the first button -autoplay-, the code would be look like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#lightgallery').lightGallery({
    pager: true
  });

  $("li.autoplay-trigger").on("click", function(){

    $("#lightgallery a:first-child > img").trigger("click");

  });

  $("li.autoplay-fullscreen").on("click", function(){

    $("#lightgallery a:first-child > img").trigger("click");

  });

});
```

---

Since, the plugin does not seem to have an option to trigger the gallery with custom settings, one solution is to destroy the gallery when the buttons are clicked and re-initialize it with custom settings.

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/kostasx/pen/RwPKdxW?editors=0010) to demonstrate this approach.

Comment: Code updated. The two buttons now trigger the lightGallery.

Comment: Checkout this fork of your codepen: https://codepen.io/kostasx/pen/RwPKdxW?editors=1010
The autoplay works by destroying the old gallery and initiating one with autoplay set to true.

Comment: yes, it is working but if we close it and open again by clicking on image then it opens as autoplay. can't we destroy it again? Also, background issues on triggering by button. LOL I am noob in js.

Comment: Yes, I've seen these issues. The library has some disadvantages when trying to trigger it with different settings.